# How can I see instance attributes of the object returned by app.request in web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

```
from bin.app import app

resp = app.request('/')

print resp.__dict__.keys()
print vars(resp)
print resp.__class__.__dict__.keys()
```

I know app.request returns an object with the data attributes 'headers', 'status' and 'data'. All I want to do is print them out, but none of the print statements above show that these exist.

Is there some way of finding these attributes (without using the help docs)?

Comment: Something like [dir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)? `[att for att in dir(resp) if not att.startswith("_")]`

Comment: what is a `bin.app.app`? Is there any material on it or is it self-defined?

Comment: It's just an instance of the application class.

Answer (score 0):

The storage object resp has a `__getattr__` method--which I found using `dir(resp)`--that you can use to list the attributes.